# Comparing two lists and adding missing items - improvement of performance

Tags: c#, list, c#-4.0, parallel-processing, compare

I have written a code which basically compares two lists, and checks their propety named TransactionID, and if the TransactionID doesn't exists in old list, it gets added to new list, which contains only old items.

So the lists are:

```
// list named: prepared - contains all old and new items 

// UserTransactions from DB  - list - contains only old transactions
```

Now I compare the two of these lists and see if the list prepared has some items that are not present in usertransaction list from db like this:

```
var ListDoAdd = prepared.Where((i) => ctx.EbayUserTransactions.Where(x => x.SearchedUserID == updatedUser.SearchedUserID).ToList().FindIndex((el) => el.TransactionID == i.TransactionID) == -1).ToList();
```

Now in the end ListDoAdd contains all items that are missing in DB.

This way that it's done is very inefficient when I work with large amounts of records.

What I have thought I could do is to load all transactions for the specific user in memory first like this:

```
var oldList = ctx.UserTransactions.Where(x => x.SearchedUserID == updatedUser.SearchedUserID).ToList()
```

And then compare the two of these lists in runtime to speed things up, rather than check every single item one by one, which this method I shown above does right now no ?

```
So now  I have:

prepared list

and 

oldList
```

Now I just have to figure out fastest possible way to compare the two lists and find missing items...

Can someone help me out with this ?

P.S. Guys if I'd do multi-threading, the only possible way to do this would be to use PLINQ, no ?

Comment: Anyone guys ???

Comment: I hope I am not missing something, but it sounds like you simply need to loop through the list that may have new items and check to see if that item is in the other list. If not then add it. A single pass of this list would accomplish this.

Comment: @JohnG yes that's it, I'd just like to write the fastest possible way so that the waiting time reduces when lists are bigger , like lets say comparing 10-15k items in both lists... That consumes a lot of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both of the list are loaded in the memory, i will suggest using set method with custom comparer, something like this:

```
public class UserTransactionByIdComaprer : IEquialityComparer<UserTransaction>
{
     pulic static readonly IEqualityComparer<UserTransaction> Instance = new UserTransactionByIdComaprer();

     public bool Equals(UserTransaction x, UserTransaction y)
     {
         return x.TransactionId == y.TransactionId;
     }

     public int GetHashCode(UserTransaction x)
     {
          return x.TransactionId.GetHashCode();
     }

}

var prepared = ....
var old = ...

var diff = prepared.Except(old, UserTransactionByIdComaprer.Instance); // this are all that are not present in the old list
```

Using set function will give you better performance mainly because it will do only enumrate the collection only once. More info: [Set Operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693100.aspx)

**About parallel**: You can parallelize the query very easily.

```
var diff = prepared.Except(old, UserTransactionByIdComaprer.Instance)
                   .AsParallel()
                   .WithDegreeOfParallelism(2)
```

I will suggest you to do some performance test. For collection with 15k elements my give you some performance boost and without the parallel stuff.

**Consideration**: If the parallel and non-parallel versions have similiar timings and you are running this on server on high load where each thread is probably important, i would suggest to use the non-parallel version.

Comment: Hey Vasil, thanks a lot. Would this work fast if both lists contained 15000 items ?

Comment: yeah sure, but i am sure that 15k elements will run under 30ms for the non-parallel version, of course depending on the machine you're using, so the parallel version is some how irelevant ;]

Comment: The machine has 36 core intel xeon and 128 GB of RAM, so I think it should run just fine ? xD

Comment: just tested 15k integers excepted with another 15k integers. the non - parallel version runned for 6ms and the parallel (2 cores) for 18ms, so there is overhead for smaller collections.

Comment: use the non-parallel, i am seeing some peformance benefit for collections with 750k elements, of course this varies from machine to machine and so on but you can aways test it yourself ;]

Comment: Vasil, yeah thx a lot man ... So tehnically speaking if old list was like this:

1,2,3,4,5 and if new list is: 1,2,3,4,5,6  => missing would be 6  and collection size for missing items would be 1 , no ? xD

Comment: Vasil , btw when I tried this implementation, I got a bunch of errors lol

Comment: can you check now, i've edited may code a bit, i guess you don't use c# so often ? i have used c# syntaxis introduced in c# 6 and some pseudo code so this probably was the issue, check if it is ok, if not share some specifics, i may help

Comment: Vasil, hold on I'll try it

Comment: Vasil, it tells me that I need to implement interface called: GetHashCode

Comment: public int GetHashCode(UserTransactions x)
        {
            return x.TransactionID.GetHashCode();
        } ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134785/discussion-between-user987-and-vasil-oreshenski).

Answer (score 1):

if I well understand, you want to compare two list.
To do it, usually we do through LINQ Left Join.
See the code below:

```
from p in context.ParentTable 
join c in context.ChildTable on p.ParentId equals c.ChildParentId into j1
from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()group j2 by p.ParentId into grouped
select new { ParentId = grouped.Key, Count = grouped.Count() }
```

I hope useful for you

Comment: Good piece of code, but u can check I wrote a more simple version of this. LINQ takes care of this quite nicely and efficiently

Answer (score 1):

If you have two sets of a type that includes a property called `TransactionID`, and you want to find all the elements of one set that are missing in the second set, you can use [`Enumerable.Except()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx).

Before you can use `Enumerable.Except()`, you'll need an implementation of `IEqualityComparer<Transaction>` because that's used to compare items in the sets.

Suppose your transaction class looks like this:

```
class Transaction
{
    public int TransactionID;
}
```

Then your implementation of  `IEqualityComparer<Transaction>` would be:

```
class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<Transaction>
{
    public bool Equals(Transaction x, Transaction y)
    {
        return x.TransactionID == y.TransactionID;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Transaction obj)
    {
        return obj.TransactionID.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Given that, then you can find missing items like so:

```
var missing = oldList.Except(newList, new Comparer());
```

For example:

```
static void Main()
{
    var oldList = new List<Transaction>
    {
        new Transaction{ TransactionID = 1 },
        new Transaction{ TransactionID = 2 },
        new Transaction{ TransactionID = 3 },
        new Transaction{ TransactionID = 4 },
        new Transaction{ TransactionID = 5 },
    };

    var newList = new List<Transaction>
    {
        new Transaction{ TransactionID = 2 },
        new Transaction{ TransactionID = 4 },
    };

    var missing = oldList.Except(newList, new Comparer());

    foreach (var item in missing) // This prints "1", "3" and "5".
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.TransactionID);
    }
}
```

---

[EDIT] Here's the full compilable app.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Transaction
    {
        public int TransactionID;
    }

    class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<Transaction>
    {
        public bool Equals(Transaction x, Transaction y)
        {
            return x.TransactionID == y.TransactionID;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Transaction obj)
        {
            return obj.TransactionID.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var oldList = createList(0, 1, 50000000);
            var newList = createList(0, 2, 50000000/2);
            var comparer = new Comparer();

            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
            {
                sw.Restart();
                var missing = oldList.Except(newList, comparer);
                Console.WriteLine(missing.Count());
                Console.WriteLine("Linq: " + sw.Elapsed);

                sw.Restart();
                missing = oldList.Except(newList, comparer).AsParallel();
                Console.WriteLine(missing.Count());
                Console.WriteLine("Plinq: " + sw.Elapsed);
            }
        }

        static List<Transaction> createList(int startingId, int idIncrement, int count)
        {
            var result = new List<Transaction>(count);

            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i, startingId += idIncrement)
                result.Add(new Transaction {TransactionID = startingId});

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this solution be more efficient than doing two parallel loops and comparing two lists?

Comment: I ask this because I'm not comparing 5-10 items in two lists, but rather 15k vs 15k items in both lists =)

Comment: @User987 It probably would be more efficient, because `Except()` has a complexity of `O(N)` rather than `O(N^2)`. You should always perform timing tests to be sure.

Comment: shouldnt this tehnically speaking be reversed?  If new transaction contains already existing items in old list , the size of missing list should be 0 , instead of 1,3 and 5?

Comment: Matthew,  so if old list was like this: 1,2,3,4,5 and if new list is: 1,2,3,4,5,6 => missing would be 6 and collection size for missing items would be 1 , no ?

Comment: @User987 Probably, I wasn't sure which way around you had your lists.

Comment: Okay man thanks ^^ ... Btw. it's giving me errors in this line of code: new Comparer() saying that: there is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'culture' of Comparer.Comparer(CultureInfo) ? :D

Comment: @User987 I've posted the full compilable app.